# 5.64.0 seems to break ContributePage

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, contribution-page

Is anyone else experiencing this?

I upgraded to 5.64.0 and my page with a Contribution shortcode ([civicrm component="contribution" id="12" mode="live" hijack="0"]) generates a fatal Wordpress error. I confirmed that it works correctly under 5.63.1.

> Wordpress sent the following information regarding the fatal eror.
> WordPress version 6.2.2 Active theme: Detroit Greenways (version 1.0)
> Current plugin: CiviCRM (version 5.64.0) PHP version 7.4.33
>
> Error Details
> ============= An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 1581 of the file
> /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php.
> Error message: Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Api4\ContributionPage' not
> found in
> /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:1581
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Cms.php(142):
> CRM_Utils_System_WordPress->checkCleanurls()
> #1 /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component.php(76):
> CRM_Utils_Check_Component_Cms::checkCleanurls(false)
> #2 /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php(215):
> CRM_Utils_Check_Component->checkAll(Array, false)
> #3 /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php(185):
> CRM_Utils_Check::checkStatus()
> #4 /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php(93):
> CRM_Utils_Check::checkAll()
> #5 /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php(255):
> CRM_Utils_Check->showPeriodicAlerts()
> #6 /home/detroi20/public_html/wp-conte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5.64 moves a whole bunch of stuff into extensions and if the upgrade doesn't go smoothly there can be a mismatch between components and extensions. Check that  both civicontribute component and the new extension are enabled.

Comment: Thanks. That got me to the solution. I looked at the extensions and the core components were all shown as not installed. I installed CiviContribute, but the Contribution page problem persisted. I disabled the CiviPledge component (still we don't use it) and then all the core component extensions were shown as installed -- and our contribute page worked again. It seems like changing the active components triggered something.